# using css-module with react?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

The React:

```
/**
 * Created by pingfengafei on 16/11/28.
 */
import React from 'react';
import HeaderContainer from './HeaderContainer';
import NavContainer from './NavContainer';
import ContentContainer from './ContentContainer';

import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from  './HomePageContainer.less';

class HomePageContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home-page-wrap-normal" styleName='home-page-wrap'>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <NavContainer />
        <ContentContainer>
          {this.props.children}
        </ContentContainer>
      </div>

    );
  }

}

export default CSSModules(HomePageContainer, styles, {allowMultiple: true});
```

The doom node :
[image]

The css style:

[image]

The webpack.config:

```
{
    test: /\.(le|c)ss$/,
    loader: "style!css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]!postcss!less"
}
```

I want to add css modules into my React project just like 
[instagram](https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en) with `react-css-modules`.

But find 2 problems:

1: Can I partly using css-module?
The child nodes of `HomePageContainer-home-page-wrap-Ql_jW` all lose css style, and the same with `home-page-wrap-normal`.

It seems that I should replace the className with sytleName in the whole project. Is there any way that I can chose where use styleName and className with both showing the correct css style.

2:Can I open sourceMap in develop model? 
The class with base64 is unreadable, I need a sourceMap connecting original class name with compiled class name.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can use `:global` inside your css/less file in order to load the style as normal css.

Please see this:
[CSS Modules - exclude class from being transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593591/css-modules-exclude-class-from-being-transformed/52594636#52594636)

To answer your second question, your class name in source map should be readable enough. You can change the following to make it even more readable:

```
localIdentName=[name]___[local]___[hash:base64:4]
```