# CSS Modules - exclude class from being transformed

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I'm using CSS modules and by far everything was working great.

We started to use external UI library along with our own one, so I'm writing components like this:

```
<div className={styles['my-component']}>
   <ExternalUIComponent />
</div>
```

Assuming that the `ExternalUIComponent` has its own class that in the final CSS file looks like this `external-ui-component`, how can I make adjust this component styling from my `css` file? The below example does not work:

```
.my-component {
   font-size: 1em;
}

.my-component .external-ui-component {
   padding: 16px;
   // Some other styling adjustments here
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please do not use inline styles as someone else suggested. Stay away from inline styles as much as you can because they can cause unnecessary re-renders.

You should use `global` instead.

```
.my-component {
    :global {
        .external-ui-component {
           padding: 16px;
           // Some other styling adjustments here
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#usage-with-preprocessors

Also, I recommend using camel case style names which is the preferred way for css-modules.
So your class name would be : `.myComponent  { ... }`

And you can use it in your code as

```
<div className={ styles.myComponent } >
```

If you wanted to add more styles , you can use the `array.join(' ')` syntax.

```
<div className={ [ styles.myComponent, styles.anotherStyle ].join(' ') } >
```

This is cleaner!

Comment: Thanks, the `:global` thing was what I was searching for, but the docs were not clear for me!

When it comes to multiple classes - I prefer `classnames` package :)

Comment: I prefer to use as few 3rd party libraries as possible. Because more libraries increases the bundled file size, and increases the project dependency which means extra potential bugs! But do whatever you are comfortable doing :)

Comment: Not working for me when using child class

Answer (score 7):

Here's a shorter form in pure CSS (i.e. no preprocessor needed):

```css
.my-component :global .external-ui-component {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This is much better indeed, thank you

Answer (score -3):

Did you try inline styles for that component ?

[https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style](http://ReactjsDocs)

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```